# Can Boost.PHP to overwrite core PHP functions, such as require_once and include?

Tags: php

I wonder it is possible to use [Boost.PHP](https://github.com/moriyoshi/boost.php/wiki/) to replace some PHP core functions logic and/or extend them. So What I want is simple: When a php script calls for `require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . "/file.php");` I want to receive `dirname(__FILE__) . "/file.php"` with my function, create somehow that required file (in my case, go to some distributed storage), and return that file to PHP interpreter as if it was desired file.

Is it possible with Boost.PHP? How could I do such thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the beavior of a core php function you can use the [`runkit`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.runkit.php) extension.

> bool runkit_function_rename ( string $funcname , string $newname )
>
> Note: By default, only userspace functions may be removed, renamed, or modified. In order to override internal functions, you must enable the runkit.internal_override setting in php.ini.

Please not that the extension is mainly used for unittesting and not used in production that often (as far as i know at least).

So you can to

```
runkit_function_rename("strlen", "org_strlen");
function strlen($string) {
    return org_strlen($string + 1); 
}
```

For things like `require` or `isset` that are language constructs and not functions see @Wrikken answer (+1)

Answer (score 6):

I don't know boost, but I doubt it, as they are *language constructs*, not functions.

You can however [write your own wrapper for a stream / protocol](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php) (either define your own, like `'mywrapper://path/to/something'`, or you can override the `file://` wrapper, but the latter means you'll have to keep flipping between override & normal, otherwise you cannot open files on your filesystem yourself :)

Comment: and can we any how change language constructs from PHP or via some extensions?

Comment: Yes, you can, as PHP is open source, so you can build it in & recompile PHP. It is however most likely not worth your time and  trouble. I'm not aware of an extenstion that does this, and just writing either a wrapper that does what you desire, of use another function that asks for / creates files before requiring in your code seems a helluvalot less work & error-proof.